# Is there anyway to retrieve count 0 when retrieve data using where clause? (Laravel Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm currently working on retrieving data using group by to get the same treasure name, total found and the same treasure amount (cap). Using the code below, I'm able to get all treasures data but when the treasure is fully claimed, it unable to show that total_left is 0.

*claimed column is a boolean where 0 is not yet been claimed.
*cap is the total treasure in the same location

***Query***

```
$treasure_hunt_data = TreasureHunt::where('claimed', '0')
                        ->selectRaw(" treasure_name, count(claimed) as total_left, cap")
                        ->groupBy(['treasure_name', 'cap'])
                        ->get();
```

***Data***

```
[
    {"treasure_name":"Location A","total_left":5,"cap":5},
    {"treasure_name":"Location B","total_left":2,"cap":2},
    {"treasure_name":"Location C","total_left":2,"cap":2},
    {"treasure_name":"Location D","total_left":10,"cap":10}
]
```

***Desired Data***

```
[
    {"treasure_name":"Location A","total_left":5,"cap":5},
    {"treasure_name":"Location B","total_left":2,"cap":2},
    {"treasure_name":"Location C","total_left":2,"cap":2},
    {"treasure_name":"Location D","total_left":10,"cap":10},
    {"treasure_name":"Location E","total_left":0,"cap":1}
]
```

**DB Data**

[image]

**Migration Details**

```
   Schema::create('treasure_hunts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('treasure_name');
        $table->boolean('claimed')->default(0);
        $table->string('cap');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Please add model and migration details and sample data for the desired output, so we have an idea what your database looks like.

Comment: @miken32, I have added the migration details and the db data

Comment: Do not post pictures of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the actual records in DB:

```
[{"id":1,"treasure_name":"Location A","claimed":1,"cap":"10","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":2,"treasure_name":"Location B","claimed":1,"cap":"220","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":3,"treasure_name":"Location C","claimed":1,"cap":"42","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":4,"treasure_name":"Location D","claimed":0,"cap":"23","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":5,"treasure_name":"Location A","claimed":1,"cap":"233","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

Try this query to retrieve the data:

```
$treasure_hunt_data = TreasureHunt::select(
            'treasure_name',
            \DB::raw('sum(case when claimed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_left'), 
            \DB::raw('sum(cap) as cap')
        )
        ->groupBy('treasure_name')
        ->get();
```

Following is the results of above mentioned query:

```
[{"treasure_name":"Location A","total_left":"2","cap":243},
{"treasure_name":"Location B","total_left":"1","cap":220},
{"treasure_name":"Location C","total_left":"1","cap":42},
{"treasure_name":"Location D","total_left":"0","cap":23}]
```

Comment: Yes this work but need make some modification on it

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a CTE (Common Table Expression) and a `DB::select` statement. For example:

```
$treasure_hunt_data = DB::select("
    with treasure_data as (
        select treasure_name, count(claimed) as total_left, cap
        from treasure_hunt
        where claimed = 0 
        group by treasure_name, cap
    )
    select * from treasure_data where total_left = 0
");
```

Which will return the result set as an array.

Comment: There will be no data return if we use where total_left = 0; without where total_left = 0; we will get [{"treasure_name":"Location A","total_left":5,"cap":5},{"treasure_name":"Location B","total_left":2,"cap":2},{"treasure_name":"Location C","total_left":2,"cap":2},{"treasure_name":"Location D","total_left":10,"cap":10}]

Comment: Edit the CTE as necessary, just an example.